# Как запускать thunderbird через cron?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crontab

Нужно каждый день запускать thunderbird по расписанию.

в терминале набираю "crontab -e", в открывшемся файле добавляю строку

```
0 17 * * * /usr/bin/thunderbird
```

или даже так для проверки

```
* 17 * * * /usr/bin/thunderbird
```

запустить thunderbird не получается

Comment: вообще, конечно, это плохая идея. но если уж очень надо, то запускайте хотя бы с помощью программы *at* вместо *crond*.

Comment: Чтобы такое провернуть, нужен как минимум работающий сеанс X-сервера.

Comment: а что хочется получить?

Comment: Если это не `ошибка молотка`, как предположил @KoVadim, то гуёвые проги я запускаю из скриптов через `gtk-launch firefox`. С кроном - хз, мож прокатит.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, почему это плохая идея?

Comment: @KoVadim, запуск thunderbird по расписанию

Comment: так можно просто не закрывать.

Comment: @KoVadim, как это сделать если пк выключается?

Comment: Поставить в автозагрузку?

Comment: @KoVadim, сейчас мне не нужно чтобы он постоянно был запущен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы cron  мог запустить графическое приложение, надо экспортировать значение DISPLAY:

```
0 17 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/thunderbird
```